# Sliding menu not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Once again I have written some Javascript using jQuery, and it works in every browser except Internet Explorer.

This time it's a sliding menu for the company website that stays at the top of the screen when you scroll down the page. In Internet Explorer the colored bar at the bottom of the menu appears to the right of where it's supposed to be, and when you scroll down the menu appears to the bottom right of where it's supposed to be. On top of that, the menu border is misaligned with the menu.

The affected page is at http://www.jacobsautomation.com/so_tooling.html, with the logic for the slide menu at http://www.jacobsautomation.com/so_slidemenu.js. Below are some pictures of the page, with Chrome left and Internet Explorer 8 right:

[Still http://www.jacobsautomation.com/Problem_Still.jpg](http://www.jacobsautomation.com/Problem_Still.jpg)
[Moving http://www.jacobsautomation.com/Problem_Moving.jpg](http://www.jacobsautomation.com/Problem_Moving.jpg)

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this working in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the complete answer, but it probably doesn't help that you're using a proprietary attribute `background` in your `<tr?`'s. You are probably looking for `style="background: xxx"`. Ditto for `height` in your `table` tag. These are actually invalid for the `DOCTYPE` specified (XHTML 1.0)

Comment: oops, deleted my comment by mistake, yes I pointed out some html issues with the </table>

Comment: Check that with tag match highlighting, its tabbed all wonky but does appear to be valid. I'm guessing the problems are with the Doctype but sometimes IE is just a fickle mistress.